# Uprobes Status on the present linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, dtrace, tracing

I know uprobes was introduced on kernel 3.5 has it survived or is it dropped, is it still available on kernel 4.x

Answer (score 0):

YES just checked the config on kernel 3.13 and UPROBES are present.